# What is TempAssemblyInfo.cs?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, assemblyinfo

My question is pretty basic, I understand what AssemblyInfo.cs is, but why is there a Temp version generates in the same Properties folder? What is it used for? Do people usually add it to their .gitignore?

Comment: There are template VS .gitignore files hanging around on the internet for github ect ect ect ect ect . instead of asking about every file type. i would start dissecting one of them

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's what is generated from the MSBuild/csproj build. I'm not sure what process would be generating that otherwise - check for nuget packages and other things in your csproj that might be generating it.

Generally should should add `bin/` and `obj/` (where this file is placed) to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: I have bin/ and obj/, but it's under Properties, which is sitting alongside both bin/ and obj/ in the same folder.